# Pass Spring model vars from JSP template to javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

Within a `<script>` tag in a jsp file I have some code that looks like this:

```
var chart = new myChart({'id': ${user.id}, 'type': ${user.type}, 'name': {user.name});
```

Where `user` is a Spring model attribute set on the server side. My problem is that passing each different field of user feels clunky. It would be nice if I could do something like this:

```
var chart = new myChart('user': "${user}");
```

However when done this way the value of `${user}` will be an object string that looks like this:
`User{id=1, type='admin', name='foo'}`
I know that I could just parse this string into an object in my external js, but it feels like there should be a cleaner way to do this. Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Going off of Cameron's answer below I could add this to my server-side controller code:

```
model.put("user", user);  
String userJSON = MyJSONSerializer.serialize(user);  
model.put("userJSON", userJSON);
```

Then in my JSP I could do:

```
var chart = new myChart({'user': JSON.parse('${userJSON}')});
```

This does solve my problem of having a messy options object, but it brings up the issue of using two model attributes for the same exact data. It would be ideal if I could use one model attribute for the `user` object, and then could somehow encode it to JSON on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the Object to JSON using a library like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/):

```
public static String objectAsJSON(Object obj) {

  try
  {
    // This could be optimized by making a static ObjectMapper
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    // Log exception and re-throw or return null
    return null; 
  }
}
```

You could either call this method before putting the objectin your model and reference the String in your JSP like this:

```
var chart = ${jsonChart};
```

Or you could write a custom taglib and call `objectAsJSON()` from there. Then the actual `myChart` object could go in your model once. Your JSP might look like:

```
var chart = <chartlib:toJson obj="${chart}" />;
```

Comment: This would work, but isn't as clean as I was hoping for. I need the user model object to render my jsp. So in my model I would have both a user and a userJson attribute. It seems smelly to use two different model attributes for the same data with different structures.

Comment: That's understandable. I've edited my answer to suggest using a custom taglib, which would let you keep just one version of the object in your model.